# IE9 shifting columns down

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

We released an application and made sure it works cross browser and cross device and it even falls back to work with IE7. Sadly we only have Windows XP machines here so could only test on IE7 and 8.

After release someone pointed out that in IE9 the home page wasn't displaying correctly. It was shifting the two columns on the right below the first column on the left. Sure enough if you try this in IE9 on your computer (a full version of IE9, not just IE10 with browser mode set to IE9) the columns shift. What's even stranger is that if you click one of the orange buttons on the left (FYI if you click-drag it has the same effect without bouncing you off the page) the layout fixes itself, and the two columns move back in line with the first column. This makes it damn hard to figure out what the problem might be.

I upgraded my home browser to IE10 after testing this and tried it and there are no problems. Even when going into Developer tools and switching the Browser Mode to IE9 and Document mode to IE9 Standards there are no issues.

I'm just wondering if any of you have come across something similar. I am of the inclination that this is some sort of IE9 bug that has nothing to do with standards compliance, since it works in IE10 with render mode set to IE9.

Any help, advice or even a quick 'yes that happens on my version of IE9 as well' would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes that happens on my version of IE9 as well.

Comment: Anyway, something weird happens with the "addthis" script on your site: it inserts a `<div>` in the `<head>`. That might not be the problem, but it's definitely a sign that _something_ is amiss. This script should probably be in the body.

Comment: And if I disable JavaScript in IE9, the site works fine.

Comment: Most of the site is actually made by other people, we just run the 'mapping' domain. Essentially we have to copy the DorsetForYou template and build our application within it, to make it look like it's all in the same site. Yeah, its a weird setup, we know :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a workaround for you, so that for the time being you will be able to correct this critical issue.
Make IE Believe that it is IE8.

You can do it by just including this meta tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

Hope it helps until we found a concrete solution.

Comment: Did you include the meta tag in your answer? I can't see anything. Ifit was an image the our web filters here will block it. Would you be able to put it as text in your answer. Sounds like a good workaround!

Comment: I have modified the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Cool, I'll have to give that a go when I get back in the office on Monday, don't think I'm just ignoring your answer!!